# Methods for complex runtime object creation

Tags: c#, design-patterns, builder

I am writing a class library which will provide functionality for communicating with USB HIDs.  There are three classes in particular which work closely with one another to provide the communication mechanism:

- `UsbHid` (models a USB HID)
- `UsbHidReport` (provides report encoding/decoding)
- `UsbHidReportStream` (provides the mechanism for read/write operations)

Instances of these classes are created at runtime (as a USB HID of interest is detected) and to facilitate their creation I have implemented the `abstract factory` pattern.  This part I am reasonably happy with.

My issue is with how I neatly manage the construction of the final `UsbHid` which has dependencies on `UsbHidReport` and `UsbHidReportStream`.

```
public class UsbHid(string str, UsbHidReport report, UsbHidReportStream stream)
```

I would ideally like to remove as much of the creation process from a `client` as possible, meaning they supply my library with required information which I then use to determine what to return.

For example:

**Would prefer to avoid**

```
var usbStream = streamFactory.Create(parameters);
var usbReport = reportFactory.Create(parameters);
var usbHid = hidFactory.Create(parameters, usbReport, usbStream);
```

**Would prefer**

```
var usbHid = creationalObject.GetHid(parameters);
```

So I was considering using the `builder` pattern to which a `client` would supply the required parameters.  It would construct instances of `UsbHidReport` and `UsbHidReportStream` for use in the creation of a `UsbHid` object of which it would subsequently return to the `client`.

Whilst I kind of like the concept of hiding the implementation of the objects creation from the `client`, yet at the same time I feel uneasy at wrapping so much of an objects creation into a single `builder` object.

I realise software is never simply black or white and everything has pro's and con's.  That said I am driving myself doolally pondering this so would like to know what other people think would be the more appropriate solution.

- Allow the `client` to implement object creation
- Use the `builder` object
- Other?

Comment: Why not have factory create the UsbHid and have `UsbHid` create `UsbHidReport` and `UsbHidReportStream`? And do you really need a factory? Key point of factories is that they give client ability to create the objects.

Comment: @Euphoric - That would seem to break the separation of concerns principle as `UsbHid` should not care about how to create its dependencies, just consume them.  The factory does provide the `client` the ability to create the objects, which concrete implementation is decided by the factory rather than the `client` though.

Comment: Are they really dependencies? For example, are you able to create usbHid with completely different usbStream and usbReport with same parameters?

Comment: @Euphoric - Sorry, I don't quite understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

if I did understand you well

```
public class UsbHid
{
...
    public UsbHid(string str)
    {
        ...
    }

    // replace virtual with abstract when the property is required

    public virtual UsbHidReport report
        {
            get{
                //do whetever you want or return your default value
                return MyDefaultReposrt;
                }
        }

    public virtual UsbHidReportStream  stream
        {
            get{
                //do whetever you want or return your default value
                return MyDefaultReportStream;
                }
        }



...
}
```

next time when you inherit the UsbHid class just override the properties

Answer (score 0):

> at the same time I feel uneasy at wrapping so much of an objects
>   creation into a single builder object

As opposed to what ? Multiple builder objects ?

The Builder pattern is precisely here to encapsulate complex object creation. If the construction were simple, you'd just put it in the object's constructor.

If a Builder starts to become bloated with, say, 5+ dependencies to assemble, it might be a sign that your object has too many responsibilities. However it's not the case here so I think Builder is just a perfect fit.

Comment: I've never used the `builder` pattern before and only discovered it whilst looking into methods for `"complex"` object creation.  My unease is due to not knowing with certainty whether it is a "good fit" for my scenario or if I am implementing something which provides little advantage versus the "complexity" it adds.